# How do I convert strings in an array to floats

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Im trying to convert all of the numbers in my list of lists and dictionary to floats.

```
my_dict={'julez': '666.56', 'jen.': '241.5', 'jon': '11.0'}
my_lst=[['julez', '666.56'], ['jen.', '241.5'], ['jon', '11.0']]
```

when I try dictionary

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    my_dict[key] = float(value)
print(my_dict)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

I have also tried to convert when in list form too

```
for sublist in my_lst:
  sublist[1] = float(sublist[1])

ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Comment: Seems to work perfectly for me. How are you running this code?

Comment: I don't get these errors; I get `NameError: name 'player_score_data' is not defined`.

Comment: Oops, typo on my part; variable is my_dict; have now edited in the question

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

try this:

```
for key in player_score_data:
    print(key, type(key), player_score_data[key], type(player_score_data[key]))
```

You will see:

```
julez <class 'str'> 666.56 <class 'float'>
jen. <class 'str'> 241.5 <class 'float'>
jon <class 'str'> 11.0 <class 'float'>
```

Comment: Ahh okay, so this seems to work when using a small dictionary. Though in my actual programme Im creating a large dictionary from a CSV which I think is causing the disparity

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, but I believe the problem is in how you are using the array indices. Tell me if this solution works (it is also scaleable if you are parsing a lot of data)

```py
mylist = [["julez", "665.46"],["brad","125.52"]]
sublist=[] # not necessary but good practice
i=0
for x in mylist:
    sublist.append([])
    #print
    sublist[i].append(x[0])
    sublist[i].append(float(x[1]))    
    i+=1
print(sublist)
```